# Ambiguous between methods or properties in C# .NET

Tags: c#

```
int n = 5;
int quorum = Math.Floor(n / 2) + 1;
```

I'm expecting quorum to have value 3. But this is the error I get in VisualStudio:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Floor(double)' and 'System.Math.Floor(decimal)'

How do I correct it? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have no need to use `Math.Floor`. Because all of your terms are integers, .NET will perform integer division which automatically truncates the remainder of the output anyway.

As for why you're getting the error, as stated above the result of integer division is still an integer. Because you can't floor an integer (there's no fractional component to round down), there's no overload of `Floor` that takes an `int`. The call would have to convert the result to a `decimal` or `double` first, and the compiler doesn't know which one you want (which is, in fact, neither).

Comment: C# will tell you when it can't perform an implicit conversion, unlike VB which seems to require you to be more explicit. (Tho it does provide a handy integer division function ("\") - eg `Dim AnInt As Integer = 10\3` - to do this.)

Answer (score 4):

n/2 is an integer division - so the result is an integer - there is actually no need to do `Math.Floor()` here at all - just doing

```
int quorum = n / 2 + 1;
```

will yield the expected result of `3`.

Answer (score 4):

Floor method accepts only double and decimal values, but int automatically fits both of them. You could use a cast from int to either decimal or double and then back to int like that:

```
int n = 5;
int quorum = (int)Math.Floor((decimal)n / 2) + 1;
```

OR

```
int n = 5;
int quorum = (int)Math.Floor((double)n / 2) + 1;
```

Comment: 2 casts and a Floor? That's silly. Integer division removes any necessity to cast or Floor. -1

Comment: He asked for it. Some people just like to discover how things work and not necessarily do it in the right way at first. I'm almost sure that clewaks knows how to make it without flooring. Of course, that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Divide by 2.0 to ensure that the resulting number is a double.  n/2 by itself doesn't tell the compiler what to cast it to when given the choice between Math.Floor(double) or Math.Floor(decimal).

```
int n = 5;
int quorum = (int)Math.Floor(n / 2.0) + 1;
```

Comment: No, I didn't try the code.  I've since corrected the error - it had to do with the return value of Floor, not the usage.